# C# When using foreach on a list of arrays, the foreach only iterates 5 times even though the list has length 86

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, list, chess

I'm writing a chess engine in C#, and I'm trying to debug move generation.  I've been using breakpoints so far to check variables, but I need a better way to debug.  Despite the fact that a breakpoint shows that this list has a length of 86, the loop only runs 5 times.  The only thing I can think of is that the arrays in the list have a length of 5, but I have no idea what would be causing this.

```
foreach (int[] debugBoard in futures)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Debug.Write(debugBoard[i].ToString().PadLeft(3, ' '));
    }
    Debug.Write("\n");
    int[,] debugOutBoard = new int[8, 8];
    Array.Copy(chessBoard.Pieces(), debugOutBoard, 64);

    if (debugBoard[0] < 0 || debugBoard[1] < 0 || debugBoard[2] < 0 || debugBoard[3] < 0 || debugBoard[0] > 7 || debugBoard[1] > 7 || debugBoard[2] > 7 || debugBoard[3] > 7) 
        break;

    debugOutBoard[debugBoard[2], debugBoard[3]] = debugOutBoard[debugBoard[0], debugBoard[1]];
    debugOutBoard[debugBoard[0], debugBoard[1]] = 0;
    int rowLength = debugOutBoard.GetLength(0);
    int colLength = debugOutBoard.GetLength(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
        {
            Debug.Write(debugOutBoard[i, j].ToString().PadLeft(3, ' '));
        }
        Debug.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Also, I tried using a concurrentbag to store moves in (I was going to multithread the move processing later on) but as soon as the foreach loop touched the concurrent bag, all the memory values of the bag changed to one value.  I've been stuck on this roadblock for days, and I really need help.

Comment: That if statement breaks out of your foreach loop... I'd write an answer but I have no idea what that if is actually trying to accomplish

Comment: Ah, very good catch.  I believe that's probably the problem.  What I meant to do is iterate to the next element.  What command would I use to do that?

Comment: I've added an answer (use `continue`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement breaks out of the for loop when its condition is met, I presume this happens for the first time on the 5th/6th iteration.

> What I meant to do is iterate to the next element. What command would I use to do that? –

You need to use `continue` instead of `break`

Answer (score 0):

If 'futures' contains 86 items the only way it could stop iterating is if an exception occurs. Visual studio (In default settings) should break when this occurs unless you handle the exception somewhere.

Wrap the whole thing in a try{} catch{} and set a breakpoint in catch and see if it hits.

Comment: Nope, the breakpoint doesn't trigger.  The only thing I can think of is that it's using the array lengths instead, except I'm still pulling data from the list.

Comment: Ah, I didn't se the break; Look at the other answers